# StaticLayout getHeight always return line count

Tags: android

I need to draw some text on canvas, this text may single line or multi lines. I found StaticLayout can fill this require. But When I create an StaticLayout and after I want to draw it, I call getHeight(), I found it always return the line count. Shouldn't this function return the number of pixels?
This is my code:

```
    m_staticLayout = new StaticLayout(m_message, textPaint, m_messageWidth,
            Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0f, false);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have found the problem. I did not set currect textsize. After currected textsize setted, getHeight seems going well. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Hi, if my explanation helped you at all, please do upvote; thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, StaticLayout is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout#StaticLayout(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.text.TextPaint,%20int,%20android.text.Layout.Alignment,%20float,%20float,%20boolean)).

The reason it probably doesn't return pixels is because we haven't drawn anything yet, we're just initializing the StaticLayout. Hence, it returns the line count which we could probably use in the future. If you are trying to draw some text on Canvas, I wouldn't recommend using `StaticLayout`.

Instead, use the Paint class, Canvas, and Bitmap. Think of paint as the ink of the Canvas(which hosts all the draw calls). Canvas will draw into your Bitmap.

We will have to create the Paint, set up it's attributes, and then host the draw call drawText to the canvas. The Canvas will then draw the text using the Paint we created.

All of this will be in an Activity which extends View, which we will then pass as the View in setContentView for our MainActivity

This is how we can implement this:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    OtherActivity otherActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        otherActivity = new OtherActivity(this);
        otherActivity.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        setContentView(otherActivity);
    }


}
```

OtherActivity.java:

```
public class OtherActivity extends View {

    public OtherActivity(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint);
    }


}
```